# install fcgi on windows 7 for serving erb on iis

Tags: ruby, iis, erb, fastcgi

I'm trying do do the simplest setup to serve ruby .erb files on a IIS 7.5 (windows7).
This is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="FastCGI" path="*.erb" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

FastCGI is installed and activated on IIS but it seems i need to install the fcgi gem which fails.
Does someone have experience with this ? Please no suggestions for other OS, VM, frameworks like rails etc..

Ik have the developper kit installed and on the path, normally i don't have problems to install and compile native extensions..
A lot of outdated or railsspecific info on the net, can't say it helps.

```
C:\Ruby193\bin>gem install fcgi
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fcgi:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for fcgiapp.h... no
checking for fastcgi/fcgiapp.h... no

make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1/ext/fcgi/gem_make.out
```